# Remove menu bar and J2ME native commands from the screen

Tags: java-me, command, statusbar, menubar, lcdui

I want to display the status bar in my J2ME application so I put this line of code in the midlet,

```
((Canvas)  (javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).getCurrent())).setFullScreenMode(false);
```

So I want to remove the whole menu bar and the native commands which appear at the bottom of the screen, is there a way to do that?

Then I will put a custom bar or use a third party such as Lwuit.

Comment: there's no API for that in midp lcdui. Find another way to meet your application requirements, whatever they are

Comment: there's no API  to remove the commands or to display the status bar?
I want to display it.any idea?

Comment: [canvas.setFullScreenMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html "API javadocs") is the best you can do with lcdui: _"By setting a Canvas into full-screen mode, the application is requesting that the Canvas occupy as much of the display space as is possible. In full-screen mode, the title and ticker are not displayed even if they are present on the Canvas, and Commands may be presented using some alternative means (such as through a pop-up menu). Note that the implementation may still consume a portion of the display..."_

Comment: Thank you but i already knew this info, so i set setFullScreenMode to false so i can show the title bar ,i really need to show the status bar and customize the menu bar.

Comment: as I said, there's nothing more that one can do with lcdui

Comment: ok thank you for your help, can i customize a title bar to look like the one in lcdui?

Comment: that would be a **[different question than what you originally asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not qute welcome")**, consider posting it separately